# Serilog SQL logging does not work when published

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, serilog

Does anyone has an idea why Serilog (SQL sink) fails when published, but works in development?

In my .NET 4.7 application I want to include logging to a SQL database with Serilog. In the past, there was just file logging which works fine.

In developement, I've started to add the following code in my Startup file. When I run this in debug, everything is working fine and records are add in the SQL table.

Serilog versions: Serilog 2.9.0, Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.1.3

```
 ColumnOptions option = new ColumnOptions
        {
            DisableTriggers = true,
            AdditionalColumns = new List<SqlColumn>() { new SqlColumn() { ColumnName = "TraceIdentifier", DataType = SqlDbType.VarChar, DataLength = 50 }, new SqlColumn() { ColumnName = "Action", DataType = SqlDbType.VarChar, DataLength = -1 }, new SqlColumn() { ColumnName = "AppName", DataType = SqlDbType.VarChar, DataLength = 50 }, new SqlColumn() { ColumnName = "UserName", DataType = SqlDbType.VarChar, DataLength = -1 } }
        };
        option.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
        option.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlLogging"], "Logs",
                autoCreateSqlTable: true, batchPostingLimit: 1000, period: new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 15), columnOptions: option)
            //.Enrich.WithProperty("AppName", "Catalogs")
            .WriteTo.File(@"D:\Apps\LogCatalog.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Once the code is published and hosted in IIS, it returns a runtime error. When I remove the WriteTo.MSSqlServer, it's working well. So nothing has changed between debug, but once published on a server, it fails.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you're also testing with IIS in development. You've also failed to mention the actual details of your runtime error -- what *is* the error? One major obvious difference between things running in IIS and things running on your machine is that IIS app pools typically run under dedicated or anonymous credentials that need to be granted explicit permission on whatever database you want to use. In particular, permission to create a table would not be a common thing to grant to an account running a web site. Look into failed request tracing.

Comment: Check the working bin folder of the project for dll files.  Then check the published results to see if the same dlls are in the same folder and the exe file.

Comment: @JeroenMostert from VS2017 I'm running in IIS Express. The error is nothing more then Runtime Error (An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.). Access to the SQL database isn't a problem from the server

Comment: @jdweng This files are all the same!

Comment: When publishing, The dlls get updated on the machine so they are compatible with the build machine.  So the publish has to be done in admin mode.  The file system has limited access on a IIS.  So drives like D: are not accessible unless you give permissions to GUEST Accounts which is the default privilege users are giving.  So I is probably better to use a Network Drive which have full permissions to store data than on IIS machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a problem with the .NET version on the server.